# How to read specific fields from multiple structure arrays in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure

I have a very large dataset arranged into multiple structure arrays in MATLAB. The structures look something like this:

```
Flight1=   

.testpoint = 1
.Mach = 0.8
.Speed = 300
.Cieling = 35000
.Data = [A] % A is an MxN matrix
```

Similarly there are multiple test points for multiple flights. Is there a way to retrieve the Data of only specified test points? For example I want to look at the Data of ALL the test points whose .Mach = 0.8 or where .testpoint = 2?

I hope I have made it clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a struct array `Flight` where `Flight( k )` is a struct with the fields you described, then:

```
sel = [ Flight(:).Mach ] == 0.8; % select all flights with Mach == 0.8
poitEightMach = Flight( sel );   % selecting them into a separate struct array

sel = [Flight(:).testpoint] == 2;
testPoint2 = Flight( sel );   % select all flights with testpoint == 2
```

Comment: The Structure is in this format:                                                                                                                                                    Flight = 

    Flight1: [1x1 struct]
    Flight2: [1x1 struct]
    Flight3: [1x1 struct]
    Flight4: [1x1 struct]                                                                      When I apply the code you mentioned, MATLAB gives me this error:                                                          Reference to non-existent field 'Mach'.

Error in fileread (line 57)
    sel = [ Flight(:).Mach ] == 0.8

Comment: @user2091834 please see my answer to [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15050234/1714410)

Comment: For the life of me I couldn't figure why I was having issues accessing multiple structure values, no matter what I tried only the first value would be returned.... Your use of square brackets fixed it all. Thank you.