# How to scan through several structures in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, structure

I have some structure arrays (like structure1, structure2, structure3,...) with similar field names. I want to scan through all the structures and return only those whose first field  is 5 (Field1==5). I have this code so far,

```
for k=1:3
    s=sprintf('Structure%d',k)
    Structure=load(s)
    idx=cellfun(@(x) x==5, {Structure.Field1})
    out=Structure(idx)
    v{k}={Structure.Field1}
end
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Reference to non-existent field 'Field1'.
```

Can someone please point out whats wrong here?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for k=1:3
    s=sprintf('Structure%d',k)
    Structure=load(s)
    eval(['newStructure(k)=Structure.' s]);
    idx(k)=cellfun(@(x) x==5, {newStructure(k).Field1})
end
%extract the structures from newStructure which have 1 in idx
out=newStructure(idx); %idx should be a logical array
for i=1:size(out,2)
    v(i)=out(i).Field1;
end
```

This should work perfectly.

Comment: There is a 'Field1' in every structure. The problem seems to be that Structures are stored in the workspace as Structure.Structure1.Field1. It doesn't work if I write {Structure.Structure(k).Field1} in the cellfun. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Why not extract out the structure into different variable as:
`newStruct=Structure.Structure1` and then proceed?

Comment: It works if I do it manually for each structure (Structure.Structure1, Structure.Structure2, ...) but how can I do that dynamically in the same loop?

Comment: It seems simple enough to do, but I am still struggling with it (I am relatively new at this). I just want to scan through multiple structures with same fields and save the structures which meets my search criteria into a separate vector. Is it even possible?

Comment: Thanx a lot. This works like a charm and returns the correct idx values (in 0 and 1). But when it comes out of the loop to out=newStructure(idx), it gives an error: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions". I'm sure its just a small glitch, but what does it mean?

Comment: It seems like 'out' can only store a single value. If more than one structures meet the search criteria then it gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if some of your saved structures do not have `'Field1'` as a field in them.
In that case, you might want to try something else.
First define a function (in m-file)

```
function res = iff( cond, true_case, false_case )
%
% conditional execution of two function handles
% 
% true_case and false_case are function handles expecting no inputs
%
if cond
   res = true_case();
else
   res = false_case();
end
```

Once you have this function you can use it in the `cellfun`

```
idx = cellfun( @(x) iff( isfield(x, 'Field1'), @() x.Field1 == 5, @() false), Structure );
```

Comment: There is a 'Field1' in every structure. The problem seems to be that Structures are stored in the workspace as Structure.Structure1.Field1. It doesn't work if I write {Structure.Structure(k).Field1} in the cellfun. Is there a way around it?

Comment: It seems simple enough to do, but I am still struggling with it (I am relatively new at this). I just want to scan through multiple structures with same fields and save the structures which meets my search criteria into a separate vector. Is it even possible?